# Calling a Parent class constructor with super() vs using Parent class name

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is it so that when I try to call the Parent class constructor using super(), I don't need to pass 'self' as an argument:

```
super().__init__(x,y)
```

Yet when I call it using the Parent class itself (named Parent in this case), a 'self' argument needs to be passed.

```
Parent.__init__(self,x,y)
```

(x and y are Parent class attributes here)

Just want to understand the background logic here. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `super()` can only be called inside a class method definition (like in `__init__`), and it always refers to itself. Therefore, there is no need, it is redundant.

Interesting you mention it: `self` used to be required just a few years ago (maybe 5... I cannot remember).

---

Think of it like calling methods.  If I have the following class:

```py
class Conversation:
  def __init__(self):
    pass
  def hi(self, name):
    print(f'How are you doing, {name}?')

convo = Conversation()
convo.hi('Jason')

(output): 'How are you doing, Jason?'
```

I did not have to specify `self` when calling `convo.hi`, I only had to pass an argument to `name`. Why?  Because `self` is always needed, and therefore redundant.

Same idea with `super()`.  :)

---